# How to Set ColumnSpan in a Custom Grid in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, grid, columnspan

I've been developing a custom grid which has some attached properties. I can set rows and columns without problem but when I try to set columnspan, it does not effect.

In my example, I have

```
<akf:DynamicGridView Grid.Row="4">
  <Label akf:DynamicGridView.ItemWidth="*" Text="Item 1" BackgroundColor="Blue" />
  <Entry akf:DynamicGridView.ItemWidth ="*" Placeholder="Item 2"  BackgroundColor="Red"/>
  <Button akf:DynamicGridView.ItemRow="1" akf:DynamicGridView.ItemColumnSpan="2"  akf:DynamicGridView.ItemWidth ="*" Text="Item 3" BackgroundColor="Green" />
</akf:DynamicGridView>
```

The first two elements are placed in the first row with two columns
and the last element is placed in the second row but **ColumnSpan** must be **2**.
But it behaves as default.

Here is my custom grid code

```
  public class DynamicGridView : Grid
  {
    public static readonly BindableProperty ItemWidthProperty = BindableProperty.CreateAttached( "ItemWidth", typeof( GridLength ), typeof( DynamicGridView ), GridLength.Auto );

    public static GridLength GetItemWidth( BindableObject view )
    {
      return (GridLength)view.GetValue( ItemWidthProperty );
    }

    public static void SetItemWidth( BindableObject view, GridLength value )
    {
      view.SetValue( ItemWidthProperty, value );
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty ItemRowProperty = BindableProperty.CreateAttached( "ItemRow", typeof( int ), typeof( DynamicGridView ), 0 );

    public static int GetItemRow( BindableObject view )
    {
      return (int)view.GetValue( ItemRowProperty );
    }

    public static void SetItemRow( BindableObject view, int value )
    {
      view.SetValue( ItemRowProperty, value );
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty ItemColumnSpanProperty = BindableProperty.CreateAttached( "ItemColumnSpan", typeof( int ), typeof( DynamicGridView ), 1 );

    public static int GetItemColumnSpan( BindableObject view )
    {
      return (int)view.GetValue( ItemColumnSpanProperty );
    }

    public static void SetItemColumnSpan( BindableObject view, int value )
    {
      view.SetValue( ItemColumnSpanProperty, value );
    }    


    public DynamicGridView()
    {
      Padding = 0;
      Margin = 0;
      ColumnSpacing = -1;
      RowSpacing = -1;

      _rowsAndColumns = new Dictionary<int, int>();
      this.ChildAdded += this.bar_ChildAdded;
    }

    Dictionary<int, int> _rowsAndColumns;
    private void bar_ChildAdded( object sender, ElementEventArgs e )
    {

      var view = e.Element as View;
      if( view != null )
      {

        var itemWidth = GetItemWidth( view);
        var itemRow = GetItemRow( view);
        var itemColumnSpan = GetItemColumnSpan(view);

        if( _rowsAndColumns.ContainsKey(itemRow))
        {
          _rowsAndColumns[ itemRow ]+=1;

        }
        else
        {
          _rowsAndColumns.Add( itemRow, 0 );
          RowDefinitions.Add( new RowDefinition() { Height= new GridLength( 1, GridUnitType.Auto) } );

        }

        if( itemColumnSpan > 1 )
        {
          SetColumnSpan( view, itemColumnSpan );             
        }

        if( _rowsAndColumns[itemRow] >= ColumnDefinitions.Count )
        {
          if( itemWidth.GridUnitType == GridUnitType.Absolute )
            ColumnDefinitions.Add( new ColumnDefinition() { Width = new GridLength( itemWidth.Value, itemWidth.GridUnitType ) } );
          else
            ColumnDefinitions.Add( new ColumnDefinition() { Width = new GridLength( 1, itemWidth.GridUnitType ) } );
        }    

        Children.Add( view, _rowsAndColumns[itemRow], itemRow );    
      }
    }
}
```

As you see in the code, if itemColumnSpan > 1 then I call SetColumnSpan method but it does not effect.

What is the problem in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I assume you've used Breakpoint to verify that SetColumnSpan line is reached.

Then, move column span set AFTER Children.Add. Add method sets ColumnSpan to default of 1.

```cs
Children.Add( view, _rowsAndColumns[itemRow], itemRow );

if( itemColumnSpan > 1 )
{
    SetColumnSpan( view, itemColumnSpan );             
}
```